# Экземпляры в ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Назрел глупый вопрос, не могу сообразить как загуглить, поэтому пришел за помощью :)

Есть следующий код:

```
//-- foo.js
class Foo {
    constructor(props) {
        this.name = 'foo';

    }
}
const foo = new Foo();
export default foo;




// bar.js
import foo from 'foo.js';

class Bar {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
export default Bar;




// bom.js
import foo from 'foo.js';

class Bom {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
export default Bom;




//main.js
import Bom from 'bom.js';
import Bar from 'bar.js';

const Bom = new Bom();
const Bar = new Bar();
```

Вопрос в следующем, foo в Bar и Bom это по сути два разных обьекта или одинаковые? Я имею ввиду, что обьявления new Foo два раза выполнится или один раз?

Comment: Почему бы просто не запустить этот код и не проверить? :-)

Comment: На будущее — всегда можно добавить в `Bar#constructor()` строчку `console.log('hi');` или `debugger;` и узнать самому. Так даже быстрее будет. :)

Comment: @shau-kote понял, спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Инициализация `import` выполняется только один раз.

Так как экспортируется уже созданный объект - именно этот объект и будет использован во всех местах.